# Highchart tooltip display time interval

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've data point every 10 minutes, and visualize using Highcharts;  however, highchart is displaying timestamp of each point in tooltip as e.g. 10:15 - 10:29, which is almost 15 minutes;
[display time interval as around 15 minutes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtygN.png)

but i want it to only display the exact timestamp of this this point.

By the way If i reduce the timespan to e.g. only 1 day, less data are rendered, then it's behaving as what I need, only displaying the timestamp.
[display only the timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8were.png)

Any idea?

Comment: could you please create a fiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Your problem may be connected with dataGrouping, you may try to disable it http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.dataGrouping